# Разные настройки, на разных серверах discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Мне нужно, чтобы на разных серверах, были разные настройки. Например на одном сервере у бота был префикс ".", а на другом "!", ну и чтобы это можно было менять с помощью команд. Также желательно хранить это не в самой программе, а в отдельном файле с названием, например, соответсвующем id сервера.

Comment: Делай через БД так удобней. [Пример](https://github.com/xzartsust/Tobi-Bot/blob/17869d2bed4afd10f9d92802bf8b5e9195d963de/Bot.py#L45)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерный код:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord as ds
import json

def prefix_func(client, message):
    with open('<путь к Вашему файлу>.json') as file:
        prefixes = json.loads(file)

    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

bot = commands.Bot(prefix_func)

@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    with open('<путь к Вашему файлу>.json') as file:
        prefixes = json.loads(file)

    prefixes[str(guild.id)] = '!' # Стандартный префикс

    with open('<путь к Вашему файлу>.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(prefixes, file, indent=4)

@bot.event
async def on_guild_leave(guild):
    with open('<путь к Вашему файлу>.json') as file:
        prefixes = json.loads(file)

    prefixes.pop(str(guild.id))

    with open('<путь к Вашему файлу>.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(prefixes, file, indent=4)

@bot.command()
async def change_prefix(ctx, prefix):
    with open('<путь к Вашему файлу>.json') as file:
        prefixes = json.loads(file)

    prefixes[str(ctx.guild.id)] = prefix

    with open('<путь к Вашему файлу>.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(prefixes, file, indent=4)
```

P.S. Я не совсем советую этот код, потому что когда пользователи одновременно вызовут команду `change_prefix`, то файл будет открыт первым вызовом, а вторым ошибка, так как файл уже открыт! [Что-то похожее, о чем я говорил](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494717/asyncio-how-to-handle-multiple-open-files-os-error)

[Видео, где был взят код](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yrHbGhem6I4)

Comment: Спасибо, но я не понимаю почему on_guild_join и on_guild_leave обрабатываются как команды, а не как события?

Comment: @Groks_45 Оу! Это моя ошибка!